# Add two numbers in ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi i am new to ajax and trying to add two numbers in ajax function here is the code:

```
$("#next_btn").click(function(){
    Display_Load();
    var page = this.title;
    var subtract = 1;
    $("#content").load("pagination_brand.php?page=" + page, Hide_Load());
          this.title = parseInt(page + 1);
    });
```

in this function i am calling the div's title value and on click i want to add 1 value in to that number just like if title is having 1 so onclick it will become 2 but here its taking as string add when i see the output it disply 11 apart of 2.

Comment: pls ignore the Display_Load() function and var subtract =1,

Comment: woooo thanks DaveRandom it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it like

```
for integers
```

parseInt(number1,10) + parseInt(1,10)
for floats/decimals 
parseFloat(number1) + parseFloat(1,10)

Answer (score 6):

It must be:

```
this.title = parseInt(page) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the number then it will treat it like integer rather than string

this.title = parseInt(page)+1;

Comment: if i have to change the value of some other div's title on this div click also whose id is next_btn then how to do that i have tried this:

Comment: $("#next_btn").title(parseInt(this.title) + 1);

Comment: Just try this : 

var title = $("#next_btn").attr("title");
title = parseInt(title)+1;
$("#next_btn").attr("title",""+title+"");